# Application uses 50% CPU after sending E-Mail

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtpclient

I have an application that I'm working on and when I try to send an E-Mail, the E-Mail sends successfully but the application then uses 50% CPU until it is closed.

Here is the send method which is causing the problem.

```
public void Send()
{
    if(System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Server))
    {
        throw new PreferenceNotSetException("Server not set");
    }
    if(System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.From))
    {
        throw new PreferenceNotSetException("E-Mail address not set.");
    }
    if(System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.To))
    {
        throw new PreferenceNotSetException("Recipients E-Mail address not set.");
    }
    using(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(this.From, this.To, this.Subject, this.FormattedText))
    {
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(this.Server);
        client.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        int temp = System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime;
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 1;
        try 
        {
            client.Send(message);
        }  
        catch(System.Exception ex) 
        {
            //For debugging only.
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());              
        }
        finally
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = temp;
            //client.Dispose(); No dispose in .Net 2.0
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what to do to make this work, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: If you break execution, what is the program doing?

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo: Don't know I'm not using an IDE so no debugging.

Comment: @Tester101, err, why not? That is the first tool to pick up if you don't know what your program is doing.

Comment: Yes, a software debugger typically is more useful than using the people at SO as one.

Comment: this doesn't look like the code that would hang. if you are not using IDE, at least implement debugging logging (using log4net) to see where the flow gets stuck.

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo: Don't know, never needed one until now.

Comment: You do know that Visual Studio Express is free, right? Also, have you ever heard of `String.IsNullOrEmpty`?

Comment: Seems like the problem is in the SmtpClient code, since the application does not hang and still functions as it should.  Control returns from the function, and the application functions normally.  The only problem is the CPU usage remains at 50%.

Comment: @John Saunders: If you don't want to help you don't have too, but you shouldn't bash on people just because they may not be as knowledgeable as you.  And yes I know VS Express is free, but I don't like it.

Comment: @Tester101 what about SharpDevelop, if you don't like VS. Anyway... not really related but a suggestion: get rid of all the if statements, you can easily combine them with && (and it doesn't have to be on a single line) In your code they only serve as noise, removing noise will allow you to focus on what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @Tester101: what are you talking about? How am I bashing on anyone? I _did_ help, by telling you which (free) tool to go get, and by telling you about the method you need to call to do your comparisons. I could have gone much further, believe me.

Comment: Oh and I just noticed you use the else statements for throwing exceptions, so combining them might not be an option. I'd still refactor out the code that actually sends the e-mail from the code that does the checking. Will Dean's answer is also a nice solution to make it cleaner. PS: if you refactor out the code, you can write a unit test that sends the e-mail, might help you as well.

Comment: @Tester Do you know if the method finishes?  Does it make it past `client.Send(message)`? Does it exit your method?  You could find out by sprinkling MessageBox.Show's to debug the old school way, but why do that when this is exactly the kind of thing that a debugger is made for?  Writing C# without an IDE or debugger is negating half the benefit of using a statically typed language.

Comment: @Tester101, why does it seems like it is the SmtpClient code? It is a synchronous call and should be completed when you exit that code. It could be very well be some update gui status loop of yours or whatever that triggers after the mail is sent. If you stop being grumpy and pick up a debugger you'll soon know where and why that code is chunking away.

Comment: @Davy8: The method finishes and the application run normally after sending the E-Mail, with the exception of eating up 50% CPU.

Comment: @Tester if the method finishes then unless the send happens asynchronously the 50% CPU usage cannot be coming from this method.  If it does send asynchronously, then there might be a problem in the SMTPClient but that's pretty unlikely.

Comment: Edited code to hurt your eyes less. Thanks @Will Dean and @qstarin for the suggestions.

Comment: @John Saunders: It's not always about what you say, but how you say it.  Your comment came across as pompous and condescending, even though you may not have intended it that way.  Some of us are still learning.

Comment: @Tester101: if you are embarassed by your code, then i suggest you improve it. Unless you're just a hobbyist, you're going to get much stronger remarks about your code - up to and including termination of employment.

Comment: @John Saunders: I am just a hobbyist (for now).  Your saying I'm going to get fired because I used If statements instead of IsNullOrEmpty?  And I don't mind being told how to improve my code, I just don't see the point of being a jerk about it on a Q/A forum where loads of people are here to learn.

Comment: @Tester101: Yes, you would at the very least be corrected about both String.IsNullOrEmpty and the nested "if" statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
      System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 1;
```

This is almost certainly what causes the problem.  It affects an internal timer, used by System.Net classes.  Not exactly sure what it does, something to do with timeouts I think.  That timer creates a threadpool thread.  After you change the value, the timer will create one thousand threadpool threads per second.  Clearly setting the value back doesn't change the timer after it was created.  The normal value for the property is 100000, a value of 1 was probably never ever tested.

Comment: I had to change this to get the E-Mail to send quickly, is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Start a new question, explain the kind of problem you noticed that made you change this setting.  In detail.

Comment: Changed the value from 1 to 1000, now all is well.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Seeing 50% CPU usage steadily seems to indicate that one of your two CPU cores is stuck in an infinite loop.  However, the method body you posted could not be the source of that infinite loop.  I suggest looking at other parts of your code for the problem.  Does your application become unresponsive while the CPU usage is at 50%?

Also, why are you changing the System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime?  I've never seen that used, and if you don't need it don't use it.

Lastly, this is more of a subjective point on style, but I'll argue that the nested if's you are using are less maintainable and harder to read than alternative structures.  I personally think checking the pre-conditions at the top of the method, without nesting conditionals, is much cleaner:

```
public void Send()
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Server))
    {
        throw new PreferenceNotSetException("Server not set");
    }

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.From))
    {
        throw new PreferenceNotSetException("E-Mail address not set.");
    }

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.To))
    {
        throw new PreferenceNotSetException("Recipients E-Mail address not set.");
    }

    using(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(this.From, this.To, this.Subject, this.FormattedText))
                { 
                   message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(this.Server);
                    client.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

                    try 
                    {
                        client.Send(message);
                    }  
                    catch(System.Exception ex) 
                    {
                        //Put this in for debugging only.
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());              
                    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to use the System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime to get the E-Mail to send properly.  Without it the E-Mail would not send for a long time, or until the application was closed.  And thank you too for the style advice, I'm still learning so it's nice to get helpful advice.

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely not an answer to your question, but it's just a demonstration of a much simpler, shorter, (clearer, I think) way of rearranging your code:

```
    public void Send()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Server))
        {
           throw new PreferenceNotSetException("Server not set");
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(From))
        {
            throw new PreferenceNotSetException("Sender's E-Mail address not set.");
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(To))
        {
            throw new PreferenceNotSetException("Recipient's E-Mail address not set.");
        }
        using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(From, To, Subject, FormattedText))
        {
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(Server))
            {
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                int temp = ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime;
                ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 1;
                try
                {
                    client.Send(message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Put this in for debugging only.
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = temp;
                    //client.Dispose(); No dispose in .Net 2.0
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

There are no functional differences other than the inclusion of a Using around the SmtpClient (As you've commented, this doesn't apply in Framework 2.0).

Comment: Thank you for the input it is very much appreciated, I was unfamiliar with String.IsNullOrEmpty. And as you mention I can't use using with SmtpClient in my situation.  It's nice to get helpful feedback, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking about this more, I suspect you have one of those hideous anti-virus systems which has intercepted winsock calls and is chewing on your outgoing mail after you send it.

What A/V are you running?

Comment: Symantec. And yes it does mess with outgoing mail, which is why I had to mess with System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime.

Comment: This was one of my first thoughts as well, but the CPU usage should spike and subside, though I cannot say all A/V's are well behaved (even major brands).

Comment: @Tester101: You really should try to disable Symantec's email scanning and see if that affects/eliminates what you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks for the help found the answer was setting System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime too low.

Comment: If you'll recall, I was actually the first to suggest eliminating the change to System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime